# Django: will using module objects in if statements result in true?

Tags: django, models

I'm fairly new to Django, but is this possible and if so what exactly is required? I checked the docs and couldn't find what I was looking for.

```
#models.py
class Car (models.Model):
    make = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    year = models.IntegerField(max_length=4)


car = Car(make = "Toyota", year = 2011)

*Code in question, will this result in true?*
if (car):
    //do stuff
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: please explain what docs you have researched. What have you learned so far, and where is your confusion. The key to getting help in StockOverflow is doing maximum amount of research and being as detailed as possible in what you do and do not understand and where your roadblocks are. This question is confusing and could use more explanation on every point.

Comment: Why didn't you try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do some thing like this:

```
car = Car.objects.create(make = "Toyota", year = 2011)

if car:
    # do some thing
    # here you have access to car object like this car.make , car.year
```